# Using Triggers vs Views to get current data status

Tags: database-design, triggers, view, database-trigger

I am new to database design and i have this question about choosing Triggers vs Views for my project. Below are some details:

Database used: MySQL

```
Table 1:

Name: - no limit on number of values
Level: - four values are possible - 1,2,3,4
Status: - four values are possible - a,b,c,d
```

Each name CAN(not mandatory, but possible) hold all the combinations of level and status.

Example:

Name: "King" can hold Level 1 status a, Level 1 status b, ......, Level 2 status a,Level 2 status b..... Level3 status a, Level 3, status b .....

Now i have to query the database to make some calculations to display them to the user via a GUI(Java Swing) that works over the network.Calculations i need are...

1. count of each status for each Level for each name. for example:

   How many "status a" in Level 1 for King.
   How many "status b" in Level 1 for King.
   How many "status c" in Level 1 for King.
   How many "status d" in Level 1 for King.
   How many "status a" in Level 2 for King.
   so on....

   Name--- Level--- status

   King---   1 ---   a

   King---   1 ---   a

   King---   1 ---   a

   King---   1 ---   b

   King---   1 ---   b

   King---   1 ---   d

   so on with Level 2 and then different names also. i want to the count of a in level 1 for name "King"

if i execute separate queries to get this data, i need to execute 320 queries if i have 20 names. which i dont want to. I have two solutions here...

Solution 1. i created a trigger.

I created Table 2:

```
   Name,Level,a_count,b_count,c_count,d_count
   King  1       3      2      0         0
    xyz   1       ...    ..... ....       ...
```

when the original Table 1 is updated the trigger adds to the count accordingly. Now i read directly from this table2.

Solution 2: Created a view that displays this data.

Name--Level--Status--Count

King  1     a      3

King  1     b      2

King  2     a      ...

So on.

With this solution i dont need to send all the queries over the network all the time. I can just call the view once ( it does execute all  the queries anyways but no need to do it from the program)

I could implement both but i want to know which solution is more efficient. I will have around 2000 rows in the parent table for each user(using my front end) and users can be any number. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Someone please let me know what can be used between Triggers and Views to get summarized data from a parent table?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did some more research and chose to use Triggers. The reasons are below:

Need : The need is to get summarized data whenever the user wants to. Currently for 20 different names i need to execute 320 queries every time the user asks for data. So the point here is how many times the user asks for data. In my application he asks for it very frequently.

So with views: the database anyway have to execute all the queries. so i end up executing 320 queries every time the user asks for data.

With triggers: i need to execute one update queries for every row update which would make around 2 queries executed for each update. I at max have 2000 rows and i would end up executing 4000 queries by the time the user updates all the rows. But when every time the user needs data i execute only 1 query to get all the data. This way the user( single or more) factor that puts load on the DB has been minimized.

i found many discussion on the web comparing Triggers vs Views which were biased towards not using one thing, but i learnt that, anything can be used as long as the application maintains its scalability without increasing the load on the DB drastically. As the load on the DB is some(x) factor user's usage, this "some(x)" should be kept as small as possible.

Please correct if my understanding is wrong, am willing to learn.

Thanks,
Raju

Answer (score 0):

> "if i execute separate queries to get this data, i need to execute 320
>   queries if i have 20 names. "

Yes, but you don't need to execute separate queries: you need one query which aggregates COUNT by `name`, `level` and `status`:

```
select name, level, status, count(*)
from your_table
group by name, level, status
```

[Find out more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).